# Angular RXJS store......when a store update is dispatched, what fields are flagged as being changed? Only the changed fields, or the whole subtree?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How does change detection work when a store issues a dispatch command?

Angular RXJS store......when a store update is dispatched, what fields are flagged as being changed?   Only the changed fields, or the whole subtree?

`this.store.dispatch(ShootManagementActions.setSelectedShooter({ shooter }));`

Assuming that the shooter object may contain 100 fields, would all 100 fields be flagged as "changed" from a change detection point of view?   Or just the actual fields that differ from prior to the dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

In NgRx, selectors are used to derive and select specific pieces of state from the store. They are functions that take the global application state as an argument and return a specific piece of data. They are memorised.

Memoization is a technique used to optimize the performance of these selectors. Memoization involves caching the result of a function based on its input parameters. If the function is called again with the same parameters, the cached result is returned instead of recomputing the result.

This leads to the answer to question, the selector functions are called again, but since the parameters do not differ, they do not emit a new value to subscribers or other selectors composed based on another selector.

Comment: Well... This is partially true and IMO the performances you mention are drastically limited by the fact that it only checks the main reference of the object received. Except that as we're working with immutable objects, we always emit new ones down the chain of selectors. Try to put console.log in all your selectors, you'll be surprised how much times they're being fired. I have raised that with benchmarks and solution but got discarded and the issue was blocked by Brandon without saying a word... Take a look here if you're interested: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2908

Comment: And if you want to give my solution a go, I've been using it on large apps in prod since I raised that ticket without any issues what so ever.

Comment: @maxime1992 ```export function isEqualCheck(a: any, b: any): boolean { 
   return a === b; 
 } ``` 1) Any thoughts on needed garbage collection here, based on OOP style comparisons leaving the unequal somewhere that isn't returned? 2) If I understand you correctly, you are implying the prerequisite that data changes require refreshing their component- so these extra iterations are quicker? 3) Would you agree optimally you would do neither as in the case of Svelte (also less hackable compilation code)???

Comment: 1) it's a pure function, it shouldn't have any side effect like saving variables from a or b somewhere more global. So 0 worries about memory leak or garbage collection. It's just a comparison. 2) I'm not sure I understand you. But I'll try to answer anyway. Yes when your data change, components are refreshed. So if you can manage to preserve object references when possible, it may save a lot of time to angular as it'll have no diff to compute (assuming you use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush). And therefore you won't even have potentially expensive repaints from the browser. 3) Never used it